# Python 3 type annotations and subclasses

Tags: python, python-3.x, types

How do I refer to 'any object that subclasses a parent class' in Python type annotations?

Example: `FooBase` is an abstract base class, from which `Foo1`, `Foo2`, etc. are subclassed. I want the function to accept any descendant of `FooBase`. Will this do:

```
def do_something(self, bar:FooBase):
    pass
```

Or will this only accept an object of class `FooBase`, which of course is impossible given that `FooBase` is abstract? In that case, do I need to build a `Union` of all cases (please God I hope not!), or can I through some other way express this relationship abstractly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> will this only accept an object of class `FooBase`?

No, this will accept any subclasses too. This is also stated in the Theory of Type Hinting PEP, specifically the [summary of Gradual Typing section](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0483/#summary-of-gradual-typing):

> A type `t1` is consistent with a type `t2` if `t1` is a subtype of `t2`. (But not the other way around.)

take a look at it for further pointers when dealing with type hints.

> do I need to build a Union of all cases.

Even if you did, all subclasses will be eliminated from the `Union` and the subclasses are going to get skipped. Try creating the `Union` you mention:

```
typing.Union[Foo1, Foo2, FooBar]
```

and the result should be `FooBar`. The fact that it is an abstract class pays no difference here, Python itself uses many abstract classes in the `typing` module.

Take for example the `Sized` abc; hinting a function with `Sized` allows any virtual subclass (classes defining `__len__`) to be substituted:

```
def foo(obj: Sized): pass

foo([1, 2, 3, 4]) # ok
foo([2, 3, 4, 5]) # ok
```

Comment: I struggle with this. I have a Baseclass, which inherits from `pytorchvision` `VisionDataset`. I inherit this class to a few subclasses `A`, `B` and `C`.  If I test `typing.Union[A, B, C, BaseClass]` all four classes are present. That is weird.
**EDIT**: My fault I used the class constructors. So my type is `type`

Answer (score 20):

Inheritance also applies to annotated types. Any instance of `Foo` which is a subtype of `FooBase` is also a valid object of the type `FooBase`. So you can pass a `FooBase` object but also a `Foo` object to the function.

If you want to limit the function to only *subclasses* of `FooBar`, you could take a look at the `Type[C]` construct: [The type of class objects](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#the-type-of-class-objects).

Answer (score 11):

Solved using `TypeVar`and PyCharm checker accepts it:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
class MyModel(BaseModel):
    pass


from typing import TypeVar
BaseModelType = TypeVar('BaseModelType', bound='BaseModel')

async def do_smth(value: BaseModelType):
    pass

# ...

await do_smth(MyModel())
```